# Maximum length of array in angular drag&drop

Tags: angular, typescript

How to set the maximum size of a array in angular. I use Drag and Drop from Angular Material, and I want to set a limit to 5 values in 'todo' and 9 in 'done'. When you try to drop an item to a limit column, the item has to go back to its original column.

```
<div cdkDropListGroup>
  <div class="example-container">
    <h2>To do</h2>

    <div
      cdkDropList
      [cdkDropListData]="todo"
      class="example-list"
      (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
      <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let item of todo" cdkDrag>{{item}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="example-container">
    <h2>Done</h2>

    <div
      cdkDropList
      [cdkDropListData]="done"
      class="example-list"
      (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
      <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let item of done" cdkDrag>{{item}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

TS:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {CdkDragDrop, moveItemInArray, transferArrayItem} from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';

/**
 * @title Drag&Drop connected sorting group
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'cdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-group-example',
  templateUrl: 'cdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-group-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['cdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-group-example.css'],
})
export class CdkDragDropConnectedSortingGroupExample {
  todo = [
    'Get to work',
    'Pick up groceries',
    'Go home',
    'Fall asleep'
  ];

  done = [
    'Get up',
    'Brush teeth',
    'Take a shower',
    'Check e-mail',
    'Walk dog'
  ];

  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
      moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    } else {
      transferArrayItem(event.previousContainer.data,
                        event.container.data,
                        event.previousIndex,
                        event.currentIndex);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use the `cdkDropListEnterPredicate` which will be called whenever an item is about to enter a new container.

**Your Component**

Here you could create 2 getter that give you info about the availability of your container to receive an element:

```
get isTodoAvailable(): boolean {
    return this.todo && this.todo.length < 5;
}
```

and

```
get isDoneAvailable(): boolean {
    return this.done && this.done.length < 9;
}
```

Then you've to setup your predicates

```
todoPredicate = (): boolean => {
    return this.isTodoAvailable;
}
```

and

```
donePredicate = (): boolean => {
    return this.isDoneAvailable;
}
```

**Your Template**

In your template you should link the predicates via `cdkDropListEnterPredicate` attribute. So, in the *todo* element you've to add the following attribute:

```
[cdkDropListEnterPredicate]="todoPredicate"
```

and in the *done* element you've to add the following attribute:

```
[cdkDropListEnterPredicate]="donePredicate"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `id` to each droplist.

```
<div cdkDropListGroup>
  <div class="example-container">
    <h2>To do</h2>

    <div
      cdkDropList
      id="todo"
      [cdkDropListData]="todo"
      class="example-list"
      (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
      <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let item of todo" cdkDrag>{{item}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="example-container">
    <h2>Done</h2>

    <div
      cdkDropList
      id="done"
      [cdkDropListData]="done"
      class="example-list"
      (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
      <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let item of done" cdkDrag>{{item}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then check the length in `drop` function.

```
  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    if (event.container.id === 'todo' && event.container.data.length >= 5) {
      return;
    }

    if (event.container.id === 'done' && event.container.data.length >= 9) {
      return;
    }
  
    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
      moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    } else {
      transferArrayItem(event.previousContainer.data,
                        event.container.data,
                        event.previousIndex,
                        event.currentIndex);
    }
  }
```